# how to cast from samsung s2 and ipad mini to chromecast?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, chrome-for-android, chromecast

A friend has just bought chromecast.

we understand we need to download chromecase browser extension

and it would be easy to watch a special chrome tab from our PC.

but how can he cast from his smasung s2? and from his mini ipad?

any additional app we should consider? like `AirCast`?

Comment: What are you trying to cast? If an app has added support for it (e.g. Netflix, YouTube, and the like) then you cast from within the app, using the button on the Action Bar. If you're looking to do something else then your options will probably vary depending on what exactly you want to cast.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to watch videos that are located on an android phone or tablet, the [LocalCast Media 2 Chromecast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.stefanpledl.localcast) app will stream videos from your device to ChromeCast.
Note that not all formats are supported and that the performance depends on the device (may be slow if old) and on the WiFi connection.